# OpenVPN force maximum session length

Tags: openvpn, timeout, session

Server: OpenVPN 2.3.8 on Ubuntu 14.04

How do I force a session to disconnect after a set time?

I want VPN sessions to last no longer than 24 hours. Currently, clients appear to be able to stay connected indefinitely.

I've looked at the `--inactive` param and that is pretty close to what I want, but I also want to force disconnect after 24 hours. i.e. VPN sessions should never last longer than 24 hours.

**Edit** OpenVPN Kill Script

I created a script to do this; it runs in an hourly cron job. I've posted it on Github here: https://github.com/poolpog/kill-openvpn-clients

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Openvpn community edition, there is no such option available, and you can only achieve this by writing custom script that uses the [OpenVPN Management Interface](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/79-management-interface.html) and `kill` command.

> ### COMMAND -- kill
>
> In server mode, kill a particlar client instance.
>
> Command examples:
>
> `kill Test-Client` -- kill the client instance having a
>                         common name of "Test-Client".
>      `kill 1.2.3.4:4000` -- kill the client instance having a
>                          source address and port of 1.2.3.4:4000
>
> Use the "status" command to see which clients are connected.

For [Openvpn Access Server](https://docs.openvpn.net/docs/access-server/openvpn-access-server-command-line-tools.html) there is such a default option available:

> live session expiration -- if a client stays connected, the token will
>   expire after 1 day by default. This value can be modified using the
>   vpn.server.session_expire key.